# When I cast Counterspell as a reaction to an enemy's Counterspell, do I do so before or after the enemy makes their spellcasting ability check?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, counterspelling

If I cast *disintegrate* and the enemy casts *counterspell*, would I wait to see the outcome of the enemy's counterspell before I cast *counterspell*?
Or would I have to just cast it without knowing (like when a Divination wizard uses their divination die with their Portent feature to replace a roll before it's made)?

Do I (the player) choose to cast *counterspell* before or after the other player or DM has made the ability check for their *counterspell*?

Comment: Related: "[What do I know, when deciding whether to cast Counterspell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46830)" and there's also this one which is just related: "[How does Counterspell work and can it be used on Silence?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110881)"

Comment: Also related: [Counterspelling a counterspell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62217/52137)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You cast the 2nd *counterspell* before the 1st *counterspell*'s ability check

*[Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell)* (PHB, 228) is clear in it's mechanics (my emphasis):

> You attempt to **interrupt** a creature in the process of casting a spell.

When using this spell, you are interrupting the casting. No effects are being resolved prior to the counterspell.

In your question, no ability check is made on the first *counterspell* because it is currently being *counterspelled*. If for some reason that second *counterspell* fails, then the ability would check on the first would complete.

This means the following is happening in order:

1. Creature A begins to cast *disintegrate*
2. Creature B sees the spell being cast and casts *counterspell*. Let's say that they are casting it at 3rd level, so there would have to be an ability check to determine if it's effective. But wait!
3. Before Creature B's spell is resolved, creature A casts *counterspell* to stop it. In the case above, Creature B was using a 3rd level slot, so the 3rd level slot spent by Creature A to counter it would be enough to stop it.
4. *Disintegrate* now finishes and target makes saving throw.

The key here is that *counterspell* is interrupting the casting of a spell. In the first *counterspell* casting, it's interrupting *disintegrate*. In the second (the attempt to stop the first *counterspell*), it's interrupting the *counterspell* against your *disintegrate*.

To be clear: When you attempt to *counterspell* the *counterspell*, you are stopping it from completing. There is no ability check for the first *counterspell* against *disintegrate* because you are interrupting the casting.

Comment: Does interrupting my own spell to cast a second spell have an effect on the first spell?

Comment: @aherocalledFrog Nope! Take a look at [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102158/can-a-caster-counterspell-a-counterspell-against-a-non-cantrip-spell-they-cast) and some of the associated links marked as dupes.

Answer (score 14):

*Counterspell* states:

> **Casting Time:** 1 reaction, which you take *when* you see a creature within 60 feet of you *casting* a spell

You can choose to counterspell *when* the other person counterspells. You cannot counterspell after the spell you're trying to interrupt is resolved.

Since *counterspell*'s own effect is to attempt to interrupt another spell, a second *counterspell* would happen before the effect of the first one takes place - i.e. before the ability check for the first *counterspell*, as that ability check is part of its effect.

Comment: This is an excellent point. *Counterspell* interrupts another spell by occurring during the spell's casting and before its effect (e.g. before the creature targeted by *disintegrate* even has to make a save, since that save and resulting effects are part of *disintegrate*'s effects). Since *counterspell*'s own effect is to attempt to interrupt another spell, a second *counterspell* would happen before the effect of the first one takes place - i.e. before the ability check for the first *counterspell*, as that is part of its effect.

Comment: @V2Blast That would be a good answer as you stated it.

Comment: @jgn This doesn't answer the question per se. The answer still leaves it vague based on your wording. Are you saying treat it like the Portent feature where I would counterspell before any roll is made to counterspell my disintegrate?

Comment: @NautArch This answer is not addressing whether my counterspell would be before or after the ability check of the first counterspell in plain simple english.

Comment: Rather than basically repeating what other answers have already said, I've simply edited part of my comment into @jgn's answer to clarify the point they're making. Hopefully they don't mind that.

Answer (score 4):

### *Counterspell* resolves before the enemy's spellcasting ability check

*Counterspell's* casting is defined as follows:

> Casting Time: 1 reaction, which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell

Notably, it's a reaction you take while the creature is *still casting* the spell, meaning the spell has not resolved. This means that a successful *Counterspell* interrupts the attempt rather than the effect.

This unfortunately (for the players at least) means that, when casting *Counterspell*, the player only knows that a spell is being cast, and maybe what the spell is. They do *not* know whether that casting attempt would have succeeded.

Comment: So you are saying it would be like the Portent feature where I would choose to counterspell before the roll is made for the other counterspell?

Comment: I think so, yes.