# Is the Command spell's "one-word command" the only verbal component of the spell, or is there more?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

The [*command*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/command) spell states, in part, that:

> You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range.

The spell also requires a Verbal component.

When I cast the *command* spell, **is the "one-word command" the only verbal component?**

Comment: Related questions on verbal components: [The verbal component of 'Suggestion'](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56998/33569), [Can people (other than the target) hear me casting Message?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116594/33569), [How loud/obvious is a wizard casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50944/33569)

Comment: Related (perhaps duplicate?): [Can NPCs tell I am casting Command?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50937/can-npcs-tell-i-am-casting-command)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### RAW: No, the one-word command of *command* is not the verbal component of that spell.

1. **With reference to [Verbal components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#VerbalV) in general:**

> Most spells require the chanting of mystic words. The words themselves
> aren't the source of the spell's power; rather, the particular
> combination of sounds, with specific pitch and resonance, sets the
> threads of magic in motion.

So, the spell *command* requires the chanting of "mystic words". This has a couple of implications:

- That's **words**, a plural, so it can't refer to the "**one-word
  command**" (which must always be a singular word).
- If the "**mystic words**" were the specific "**one-word command**",
  then that would mean all of the various uses of *command* would be
  different spells with different "mystic words", not the same spell
  with just one set of "mystic words" to be learned.

2. **Furthermore, regarding [*command*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/command) specifically**:

> The **spell has no effect if the target** is undead, if it **doesn’t
> understand your language**, or if your command is directly harmful to
> it.

So the command in this spell must be intelligible to the target. "Mystic words" implies that to the vast majority of hearers, the verbal component of a spell is not intelligible. So, if people had to understand the **mystic words** in order to be affected by the spell, it would render it almost useless.

3. **Support from rulings on similar spells:**

For further evidence of this ruling, see [this similar question regarding the *suggestion* spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56998/the-verbal-component-of-suggestion) - and specifically [this text from the *Sage Advice Compendium* (p. 19) about *suggestion*](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=19):

> Verbal components are mystic words (*PH*, 203), not normal speech. The
> spell’s suggestion is an intelligible utterance that is separate from
> the verbal component.

The *suggestion* spell's suggestion is not part of its verbal components, so it makes sense for the same to be true of the *command* spell's command.

### However, could you homebrew it otherwise?

While it isn't RAW, a DM could allow the one-word command from the *command* spell to function as that spell's verbal component in their game.

As the "mystic words" are normally the only component of this spell (it doesn't have somatic or material components), a DM who removes these mystic words might find that doing so complicates the question of whether or not an observer would be able to perceive that a spell has even been cast. If they rule that casting *command* is now imperceptible to an observer (its only component now being a perfectly intelligible phrase), then that would represent a strong buff to this spell, under the right conditions. Unless ruthlessly exploited, however, even this is unlikely to be game-breaking (though it could be an interesting tool to give a BBEG).

In general, though, spell components are there to help balance spellcasting, in terms of action economy and cost. So, extrapolating this exception and applying this principle to other spells (amalgamating or removing components), as a consequence of this ruling, could cause wider balance issues long-term.

Comment: To address your point about perceiving a *command* spell whose verbal component was the command word: as DM I get around this by saying that the command word is the verbal component (which allows players some cool roleplay moments by working the word into a sentence) but stating that the command word is accompanied by some special effect (like otherwordly echoes, or a deep rumbling reverb, or coming out in another voice) that makes it clear that this word had magic behind it (thus making it perceivable). Functionally the same, but cooler to roleplay.

Comment: @anaximander - That's a pretty common technique in visual media as well, and it works really well to convey "This is a command that Must Be Obeyed".

Comment: It also should be noted that Xanathat's Guide to Everything states that a spell would be perceived as cast if it has V, S or M components (even stipulating that it doesn't matter if a focus is used for material components). So it would make sense that even if it were just a single word command, the effect is the same, RAW you perceive it being cast.

Comment: Of note the quote from the Sage Advice Compendium *explicitly* addresses the *command* spell: "[...] The command spell is the simplest example of this principle. The utterance of the verbal component is separate from, and precedes, any verbal utterance that would bring about the spell’s effect"

Comment: Note that the SAC ruling actually addresses *command* explicitly: "Verbal components are mystic words (*PH*, 203), not normal speech. The spell’s suggestion is an intelligible utterance that is separate from the verbal component. The *command* spell is the simplest example of this principle. The utterance of the verbal component is separate from, and precedes, any verbal utterance that would bring about the spell’s effect." You may want to update your answer to include that part of the quote, as it directly supports that part of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

This is addressed in the official ruling from the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=19) for a similar question about the *suggestion* spell:

> **Is the sentence of suggestion in the *suggestion* spell the
> verbal component, or is the verbal component separate?**
>
> Verbal components are mystic words (*PH*, 203), not normal speech. The spell’s suggestion is an intelligible utterance that is separate from the verbal component. The *command* spell is the simplest example of this principle. The utterance of the verbal component is separate from, and precedes, any verbal utterance that would bring about the spell’s effect.

The [*suggestion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion) and [*command*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/command) spells both require a Verbal component and speaking *something* that must be understood by the target; thus, the same ruling can be applied:

> The spell's one-word-command is a **separate**, intelligible utterance.

When a spell requires a verbal component, it always requires first **completing the mystic words** as part of the casting of the spell; only then does the spell's effect occur as given in the description (which includes the one-word command, in this case).